# Speed up parsing of XML in C# Compact Framework (using XmlTextReader & XElement)?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, sql-server-ce, compact-framework

I am trying to import large XML file (goal is 100,000 rows) to import it to SQL CE database file (with Compact Framework 3.5 and SQL CE 3.5).

Recently I wrote some code to do that, where I use XmlTextReader with XElement to parse my XML input file and then SqlCeCommand.TaableDirect/SqlCeResultSet/Insert to write it to database file. (Complete code below)...

At the moment I am doing test with ~25,000 rows file and my performance get bottlenecked at line which parse each line of my input XML file.

```
xElem = XElement.Parse(xmlTextReader.ReadOuterXml());
```

Performing some runs on emulator... It turns out that running a complete code takes 93 seconds, running empty if statement inside while loop (with everything commented out) takes 14 seconds, and running only XElement.Parse in same if statement takes 60 seconds. So XElement.Parse takes about half of what it takes to run the entire code (46 seconds vs. 93). Same was observed on real devices (not emulator).

What can I do to speed this up? xmlTextReader.ReadOuterXml() consists of following: `<item><Index>121fg12e<Index><Name>John</Name>.........<Notes>John's profile</Notes></item>` (where I just basically want to extract values inside tags).

Below is my complete code:

```
XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(modFunctions.InFName);
XElement xElem = new XElement("item");
using (SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
{
    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        cn.Open();
    using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandText = "item";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
        using (SqlCeResultSet rs = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable))
        {
            SqlCeUpdatableRecord record = rs.CreateRecord();
            while (xmlTextReader.Read())
            {
                if (xmlTextReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                    xmlTextReader.LocalName == "item" &&
                    xmlTextReader.IsStartElement() == true)
                {
                    xElem = XElement.Parse(xmlTextReader.ReadOuterXml());

                    values[0] = (string)xDoc.Root.Element("Index"); // 0
                    values[1] = (string)xDoc.Root.Element("Name"); // 1
                    ~~~
                    values[13] = (string)xDoc.Root.Element("Notes"); // 13

                    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(values[i]))
                            record.SetValue(i, values[i]); // 0
                    }

                    rs.Insert(record);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're needlessly converting the XML to a string and back again.

Call `XElement.FromReader(xmlTextReader)` instead.

Comment: Thank you! This helped. It brought it down to 25 seconds from 60 seconds (running only this line in if statement). I did had to cast it from XNode to XElement... I am not sure if i can avoid it somehow:      xElem = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xmlTextReader);